# Do I need decoupling capacitors in this schematic?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, schematics, decoupling-capacitor

I just read about 'decoupling capacitors' to stabilize the voltage. I have some small voltage drops on this schematic when I made it into a PCB.

Can capacitors would solve the problem?

If yes, where do I have to put them?

[image]

Here's the PCB view.  Maybe there is something wrong with it:
[image]

I measured on the M1/M2/M3 outputs. When I press SW1, I've 5.2V. When I press SW1 & SW2 I'm at 5.0V. When I press SW1 & SW2 & SW3 I land at 4.8V. Measured on the same (M1) output with both probes on GND and VCC of the connector.

Comment: Where exactly you are measuring voltage drops? And doesn't the regulator already have enough bypassing?

Comment: Unlikely that the caps would solve the voltage drops. (They would help with transients, not DC issues). My bet is that you are measuring the voltage of the transistor when its on.

Comment: I measure on the M1/M2/M3 outputs. When I press SW1, I've 5.2V. When I press SW1 & SW2 I'm at 5.0V. When I press SW1 & SW2 & SW3 I land at 4.8V. Measured on the same (M1) output with both probes on GND and VCC of the connector

Comment: Do you have the motors connected to M1, M2, and M3?

Comment: The 'M' here does not necessarily stand for a motor. A small fog module, a fan and a pump will be connected. No, I have only tested the connections with the multimeter without the connected modules.

Comment: Assume you always need decoupling capacitors for everything unless proved otherwise by simulation and test. Decoupling capacitors won't help voltage drop at all.

Comment: Likely your circuit as a load has nothing to do with voltage drops and the voltage drop comes from the power supply itself or the wiring when load is added. Just measure the power supply itself when there is no load or some load.

Comment: Is C2 a tantalum cap?  Some data sheets vary on the recommended cap value but it seems the ESR is important too. The TI data sheet says a 10uF tantalum is required on the output.  Some LDO regulators are sensitive to very low ESR. Tantalum ESR is low but not extremely low. Check if your output is unstable (or oscillating), that could explain voltage variations if your are only measuring with just a DVM.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a decoupling (bypass) capacitor (C1) where it's needed (across the supply of U4). So, no, you don't need more.

Also, no, it won't solve your long-term voltage drop problem. Small decoupling capacitors supply short bursts (~microseconds) of power, not long-term power.